# Dropbox PHP v2 upload issue

Tags: php, file-upload, dropbox-api

I did a `php` `cURL` code, the result is success but the problem it return the size 0, can anyone help me out, I do use the code on this page [Dropbox v2 API - large file uploads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34162156/dropbox-v2-api-large-file-uploads)
I'm not sure why the file size is zero. can anyone help me out?

Also this is the return from the request cURL

```
{"name": "2.jpg", "path_lower": "/images/2.jpg", "id": "id:92FZUH08Y6AAAAAVVAAAEA", "client_modified": "2015-12-10T11:02:38Z", "server_modified": "2015-12-10T11:02:38Z", "rev": "1c40f677f1", "size": 0}
```

Thanks,

UPDATE (CODE):

```
$filename='2.jpg';
$cheaders = array('Authorization: Bearer =TOKEN=','Content-Type: application/octet-stream','Dropbox-API-Arg: {"path":"/images/'.$filename.'", "mode":"add"}');
$ch = curl_init('https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $cheaders );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
$fpath = '/home2/public_html/uploads/'.$filename;
$fp = fopen($fpath, 'rb');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($fpath));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: is it an  issue if my site don't use https and the cURL has no certification attach?

Comment: I just want to add more details, this issue I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059681/dropbox-core-api-0-bytes-size-in-metadata-for-image?rq=1 , its the same thing happens to my script if I run the API it return 0  for the file size

Comment: No, that wouldn't be an issue. Can you log the size of the file? E.g. `echo filesize($fpath)`. Maybe the file's empty?

Comment: I already did and has a filesize, it has 278kb

Comment: I think the issue is that `CURLOPT_INFILE` is only by supported by curl for PUT, but the API only uses POST. I can't find a better way to do this than `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, fread($fp, $filesize));` but that's not good for large files of course.

Comment: @Greg thanks that works but as you said it is not properly working on large files, I will have to work it on upload session. Thanks, I will try to contact dropbox support to ask them for possible solution for CURLOPT_INFILE

Comment: I am Dropbox developer support, but unfortunately the matter of `CURLOPT_INFILE` is about curl and not Dropbox itself, so I can't offer much help there in particular.

Comment: Ah, nevermind, we figured out a way. I'm posting an answer.

Answer (score 2):

This version of the code seems to trick curl into acting like it's a PUT request, but has it send "POST" as necessary.

```
<?php

$path = 'test_php_upload.txt';
$fp = fopen($path, 'rb');
$size = filesize($path);

$cheaders = array('Authorization: Bearer =TOKEN=',
                  'Content-Type: application/octet-stream',
                  'Dropbox-API-Arg: {"path":"/test/'.$path.'", "mode":"add"}');

$ch = curl_init('https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $cheaders);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, $size);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

echo $response;
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);

?>
```

That yields:

```
{"name": "test_php_upload.txt", "path_lower": "/test/test_php_upload.txt", "id": "id:25N5ksooX-sAAAAAAAHcWg", "client_modified": "2015-12-10T22:35:07Z", "server_modified": "2015-12-10T22:35:07Z", "rev": "56384021eccc7", "size": 15}
```

Comment: Thanks, spent almost 2 days to figure out this